# Page referencing itself in HTML iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a webpage (which I will refer to as foo.php) that has an iframe in it that should contain another page (bar.php). However, it instead of sourcing bar.php, it sources foo.php/bar.php. This creates another foo.php page that contains an iframe that contains another foo.php page that contains an iframe... you get the picture. Weirdly enough, I have other pages with iframes that are working just fine. This is the code:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 50px;" src="bar.php"></iframe>
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; the page that linked to foo.php did so with the address "foo.php/". Removing the slash fixed the problem.